# GetAxis("Mouse X/Y") does not work with virtual mouse

Tags: unity-game-engine, autohotkey

I recently tried writing a bot in python for a unity game  to control the character using a virtual mouse like in pyautogui or autohotkey. The game has multiple camera modes. One that uses the cursor location and another that uses GetAxis("Mouse X/Y"). Neither the library I'm using, pyautogui, pydirectinput, or even an autohotkey macro fails to move the mouse when on the option that use GetAxis() although it works on the camera that uses the cursor location. Why is this the case?
Example of a script that fails when using GetAxis():
Yoinked from another stack overflow post since I needed an ahk example as well:

```
CoordMode, mouse, screen

toggle := 0, fixedY := A_ScreenHeight/2 ; choose the y you like

F1::
MouseGetPos, MouseX, MouseY
if toggle := !toggle
 gosub, MoveTheMouse
else
 SetTimer, MoveTheMouse, off
return

MoveTheMouse:
Random, x, 1, % A_ScreenWidth
MouseMove, %x%, %fixedY%, 100
Random, Time, 1000*60, 1000*60*5
SetTimer, MoveTheMouse, -%time%  ; every 3 seconds 
return
```

The C# code used for movement is:

```cs
case CAMERA_TYPE.CAMERA_THAT_WORKS_WITH_BOT:
                if (Input.mousePosition.x < (float)Screen.width * 0.4f)
                {
                    mainT.RotateAround(mainT.position, Vector3.up, -(((float)Screen.width * 0.4f - Input.mousePosition.x) / (float)Screen.width * 0.4f) * getSensitivityMultiWithDeltaTime() * 150f);
                }
                else if (Input.mousePosition.x > (float)Screen.width * 0.6f)
                {
                    mainT.RotateAround(mainT.position, Vector3.up, (Input.mousePosition.x - (float)Screen.width * 0.6f) / (float)Screen.width * 0.4f * getSensitivityMultiWithDeltaTime() * 150f);
                }
                mainT.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(140f * ((float)Screen.height * 0.6f - Input.mousePosition.y) / (float)Screen.height * 0.5f, mainT.rotation.eulerAngles.y, mainT.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
                mainT.position -= mainT.forward * this.distance * this.distanceMulti * this.distanceOffsetMulti;
                break;
            case CAMERA_TYPE.CAMERA_THAT_FAILS_WITH_BOT:
                if (!CustomInputs.Inputs.menuOn)
                {
                    Screen.lockCursor = true;
                }
                float num5 =0f;
                float num6 =0f;
                if (((int)GameManager.settings[300]) == 0)
                {
                    num5 = (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 10f) * this.getSensitivityMulti();
                    num6 = ((-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 10f) * this.getSensitivityMulti()) * this.getReverse();
                }
                else if (((int)GameManager.settings[300]) == 1)
                {
                    num5 = (Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * 10f) * this.getSensitivityMulti();
                    num6 = ((-Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * 10f) * this.getSensitivityMulti()) * this.getReverse();
                }

                mainT.RotateAround(mainT.position, Vector3.up, num5);
                float num7 = mainT.rotation.eulerAngles.x % 360f;
                float num8 = num7 + num6;
                if (((num6 <= 0f) || (((num7 >= 260f) || (num8 <= 260f)) && ((num7 >= 80f) || (num8 <= 80f)))) && ((num6 >= 0f) || (((num7 <= 280f) || (num8 >= 280f)) && ((num7 <= 100f) || (num8 >= 100f)))))
                {
                    mainT.RotateAround(mainT.position, mainT.right, num6);
                }
                mainT.position -= (Vector3)(((mainT.forward * this.distance) * this.distanceMulti) * this.distanceOffsetMulti);
                break;
```

Some of this code is incomprehensible due to being decompiled. Also a note, don't worry about modding here as the game has basically been abandoned by the dev for 4 years and is now running on community servers.

After some further searching I found that GetAxis may use the mouse velocity/acceleration and I don't think these mouse move functions affect that in any way. In my use case what I would need for testing is a way to read the mouse acceleration/velocity and a way to move set my mouse's acceleration/velocity. Please let me know if I have the right idea here and any references to material related to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help to also include the according `c#` code you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I found was to use a windows dll call:
AHK:

```
DllCall("mouse_event", "UInt", 0x01, "UInt", 100, "UInt", 100)
```

python:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x01, x, y, 0, 0)
```